# Summer 18 | Custom Lightning Component Tab not does not display in lightning record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, summer-18

I am having a lightning component tab inside my account record page. It is having a lightning component inside.

It is not coming up in Summer 18 sandbox whereas it is showing up fine in Spring 18 Production.

FYI: I have added Lightning Component Inside and I have activated the record page.

I tried with a test component with a simple text. That is also not coming up.

Component Code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexiPage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"> 
"Test Component" 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Is your componet bit broken? Broken components wouldbe ignored from Apps in Summer 18.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_pages_render_with_broken_cmps.htm

Comment: Can you test that component in aura:application and see if the component is visible and behaving properly.

Comment: No. It is coming up fine when i use it inside VF page in detail page layout.

Comment: Sometime we might have to wait few minutes and do hard refresh using CTRL+F5 as it takes time for changes to propogate.

Comment: This is not part of any change. It was a working section in Spring 18. It is coming up fine in production (which is Spring 18). Only Sandbox is having this issue.

Comment: I tried using the component inside aura:application. It is coming up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component has only implemented `flexipage:availableForRecordHome` which should have been enough.

Probably after Summer 18 `flexipage:availableForRecordHome` also needs '`flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes`' for pages to be visible in application.

[image]

Adding an extra interface fixed the issue.

```
<aura:component implements="flexiPage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"> 
"Test Component" 
</aura:component>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm